# Connecting MSP430fg4618 with hyperterminal

Tags: serial-port, uart, msp430, hyperterminal

I have an MSP430 (FG4618/F2013) Experimental Board connected to Windows 7 via MSP-FET430UIF/USB cable as a power and Serial RS232 cable.

I am trying to run the sample code that reads the input and echoes back to the HyperTerminal.

```
#include <msp430xG46x.h> 
void main(void)
{
     WDTCTL = WDTPW+WDTHOLD;    // Stop WDT
     P5DIR |= BIT1;             // Set P5.1 to be output
     P2SEL |= BIT4 + BIT5;      // P2.4,5 = USCI_A0 RXD/TXD
     UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2;      // SMCLK
     UCA0BR0 = 0x09;            // 1MHz/115200 (lower byte)
     UCA0BR1 = 0x00;            // 1MHz/115200 (upper byte)
     UCA0MCTL = 0x02;           // Modulation (UCBRS0=0x01)(UCOS16=0)
     UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;      // **Initialize USCI state machine**
     IE2 |= UCA0RXIE;           // Enable USCI_A0 RX interrupt
     _BIS_SR(LPM0_bits + GIE);  // Enter LPM0, interrupts enabled
 } 
 // Echo back RXed character, confirm TX buffer is ready first
 #pragma vector=USCIAB0RX_VECTOR
 __interrupt void USCIA0RX_ISR (void)
{
   while(!(IFG2&UCA0TXIFG));  // Wait until can transmit
      UCA0TXBUF = UCA0RXBUF;     // TX -> RXed character
  P5OUT^=BIT1;               // Toggle LED4
}
```

Since this is a sample demo code, my issue is not with the code, but with the setup. When I run the following code in IAR editor, I pick the COM149 port in the FET Debugger settings since that is the port recognized via the Device Manager.

Then I try to connect the HyperTerminal to that same port and it says "Another device is using the selected Telephony device"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That COM port is used by the TI tools to communicate with the FET.

According to the schematic in the MSP-EXP430FG4618 manual, UCA0TXD and UCA0RXD are connected to the isolated RS-232 port, and to pins 5 and 6 of header H4. Neither of these is connected to the FET.

And the MSP-FET430UIF does not have a backchannel/application UART.